# Split a list into chunks by a number of chars [Python]

Tags: python, list, sorting, chunks

I've got a list of words (domains in my case) and I need to split this list into groups, each group should contain not more than N chars (=bytes). One important thing is that the last word in each group should not break in the middle. I mean there should not be situations like:

```
google.com
yahoo.com
bin
```

In my code I only managed to retrieve the first group, I don't know how to make a proper loop to split the list into multiple chunks.

```
domains = ['google.com','yahoo.com','bing.com','microsoft.com','apple.com','amazon.com']


domains = list(domains)
text = ""
chars_sent=0
max_chars=20

for each_domain in domains:
    if chars_sent > max_chars:
        chars_sent = 0
        break
    text += each_domain+"\n"
    chars_sent += len((str(each_domain)))
print(text)
```

Expected output:

```
google.com
yahoo.com <--- 19 chars in this part

bing.com <--- 8 chars in this part

microsoft.com <--- 13 chars in this part

apple.com
amazon.com <--- 19 chars in this part
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to check whether adding the new element will exceed the maximum *before* adding it to the result.

And when you hit the limit you shouldn't break out of the loop, just add a blank line to the result.

```
domains = ['google.com','yahoo.com','bing.com','microsoft.com','apple.com','amazon.com']

text = ""
chars_sent=0
max_chars=20

for each_domain in domains:
    if chars_sent + len(each_domain) > max_chars:
        chars_sent = 0
        text += "\n"
    text += each_domain+"\n"
    chars_sent += len(each_domain)

print(text)
```

There's no need to use `list(domain)` since it's already a list, or `str(each_domain)` because it's already a string.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there!
Here's another answer, if you want to get your result as nested lists (might be more pratical to use than plain text).

```
domains = ['google.com', 'yahoo.com', 'bing.com', 'microsoft.com', 'apple.com', 'amazon.com']
max_chars = 20

chunk_size = 0
chunks = [[]]
for domain in domains:
    if chunk_size + len(domain) > max_chars:
        chunk_size = 0
        chunks.append([])
    
    chunks[-1].append(domain)
    chunk_size += len(domain)

print(chunks)
```

Result:

```
[
    ['google.com', 'yahoo.com'],
    ['bing.com'],
    ['microsoft.com'],
    ['apple.com', 'amazon.com']
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
domains = ['google.com','yahoo.com','bing.com','microsoft.com','apple.com','amazon.com']
max_chars=20
out = [""]
for d in domains:
    if len(d) + len(out[-1].strip()) > max_chars:
        out.append(f"{d}\n")
    else:
        out[-1] = f"{out[-1].strip()}\n{d}\n"

print(*out, sep="\n")
```

---

```
google.com
yahoo.com

bing.com

microsoft.com

apple.com
amazon.com
```

---

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/0f1ea1946d)